# Aggregation based on Junction object in a subquery

Tags: soql

I have 2 master objects, A__c and B__c. An object C__c has the 2 reference fields A(child of A__c) and B(child of B__c). There is also another object D__c which has a lookup field(B) to B__c. I need to write a SOQL query something like the below:

```
Select B__r.Name, B__r.Id, Count(A__r.Id) countA,
(select Max(CreatedDate) from D__c Dobj where Dobj.B__r.Id = Aobj.B__r.Id) from A__c Aobj
group by B__r.Name, B__r.Id
```

I am new to SOQL and from SQL background, I get one or the other type of errors with this. My query tries to get records from C__c which does not have a master-detail or lookup field to D__c. It has a link to D__c through B__c. Please suggest me how this can be done in SOQL.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your words describing what you want to achieve, you appear to be looking for a [`Left Anti Join`](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com#Left_Anti_Join):

```
SELECT ... FROM A__c
WHERE B__c NOT IN (
    SELECT B__c FROM D__c
)
```

However, you actually need to retrieve data rolled up from `D__c` to `B__c`, you will need to create a rollup field. Even though you are using a `Lookup Relationship`, it is still possible using [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).